# Is it allowed to call anyone "son" except our own child?

Tags: family, greetings

I have a cousin brother who is around 7 to 8 years older than me. He calls me betaa (son in urdu) on some occasion purposely or may be just for fun. I don't like it. I want to know if it's allowed in Islam to call anyone son except to our own child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as I know there is a hadeeth in "muslim" that "anas ibn malek" reported that **" Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) addressed me 'O My Son' "**

```
Reference                        : Sahih Muslim 2151
In-book reference                : Book 38, Hadith 38
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Book 25, Hadith 5351
```

[the hadeeth reference](http://sunnah.com/muslim/38/38)

also check this [fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/118666) - but in Arabic -

صحيح مسلم» كتاب الآداب» باب جواز قوله لغير ابنه يا بني واستحبابه للملاطفة

**"قال قال لي رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يا بني"**

this is not a fatwa (I'm not a scholar or mofty)  , but I think according to muslim hadeeth you are allowed to call a kid "son" as some sort of kindness, **unless** it is considered offensive word in some cultures or you express it in an impolite way